# Center footer content vertically and horizontally independently of footer size and tag count

Tags: html, css

I want center all content in footer under `id="footer-content"` to always in horizontally and vertically centered independently of footer size and tag count. If change the footer size or add/remove some tag, the footer content must stay center horizontal and vertical.

```
 #footer {
      min-height: 100px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-style: dashed;
    }  

<footer id="footer">
  <div id="footer-content">
    <p>My text</p>
    <p>My text</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but given a `height` to its child, this `flexbox` solution is bound to work. Both horizontally and vertically:

```
#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 90px); <!--Arbitrary-->
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

It's important to have a `height` - as mentioned above - otherwise the vertical align will not work. You can use many units to set it, such as `px`, `vh`, `em`, etc.